# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1103 (42000)

Tags: mysql-python

I get the following error while executing this query in mysql:

```
'create table DDB_CHANGE_via_mailbox_iocb_modifier_0x1_device_id_0x2_state_0x23_tran_up_error_0x0_flags_0x884e0000 (s_no int primary key not null, time varchar(25) not null, component varchar(50) not null, message varchar(255) not null, complete_id int not null)'
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 559,
>   in execute
>       self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line
>   494, in cmd_query
>       result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))   File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line
>   396, in _handle_result
>       raise errors.get_exception(packet) mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1103 (42000): Incorrect table
>   name
>   'DDB_CHANGE_via_mailbox_iocb_modifier_0x1_device_id_0x2_state_0x23_tran_up_error_0x0_flags_0x884e0000

'

I am using xampp local host mysql and executing queries in python using mysql connector.
Am i entering some character in the table name which is not allowed?
I read somewhere that enclosing table name in backticks solves that problem. But I get the same error even after doing that.

Edit: Okay, apparently you can't have a table name of more than 64 characters which seems to be the problem in my case. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

create table 'DDB_CHANGE_via_mailbox_iocb_modifier_0x1_device_id_0x2_state_0x23_tran_up_error_0x0_flags_0x884e0000' (
's_no' int primary key not null, 
'time' varchar(25) not null, 
'component' varchar(50) not null, 
'message' varchar(255) not null, 
'complete_id' int not null)

Comment: `dbCursoe.execute("create table 'DDB_CHANGE_via_mailbox_iocb_modifier_0x1_device_id_0x2_state_0x23_tran_up_error_0x0_flags_0x884e0000' ( 's_no' int primary key not null, 'time' varchar(25) not null, 'component' varchar(50) not null, 'message' varchar(255) not null, 'complete_id' int not null)")`

Executing this gives the error : _mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax_

Comment: Again, using backtics(`) instead of single quotes to enter the table name gives me the same error as my question( incorrect table name).
Maybe I am using some character in my table name which is not allowed?